# How to disable complete list view

Tags: android, listview

I want to disable entire list view at the first instance. So how to achieve that?
                   I have put a button( All buttons are click able from the item in listview) on the customized list view so on click of that button i am doing some processing.After finishing that i want to enable only that item in listview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a editext and a button as row items..
In your getview method of your adapter..

```
         edittext.setClickable(false);
    edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

and in onclick of the button put

```
   private OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    edittext.setClickable(true);
    edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     }
};
 button.setonClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
```